# How to upgrade Kali Linux 1.0.6 to 1.0.8 (Debian) using an offline ISO image?

Tags: debian, upgrade, kali-linux

I want to upgrade Kali Linux to 1.0.6 to Kali 1.0.8. I realized that I can do this using the command:

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But I have a slow network and it would take forever to download the 1 GB (or so) of archives. Besides, I already have an offline 1.0.8 ISO.

I do not want to do the traditional fresh install because I have installed a lot of custom packages and configurations on my machine.

I want to upgrade from 1.0.6 to 1.0.8 using the offline ISO I have (and keep the existing settings and everything).

Any thoughts on how I should do this?

Answer (score 2):

Mount the ISO to `/mnt` directory

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop /path/to/iso /mnt/
```

Modify the `/etc/apt/sources.list`
Add:

```
deb file:///mnt kali main contrib non-free
```

Comment:
Comment out all other repository locations from the file except the about one.

Update the system

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Un-comment
We have now updated the system from the ISO, now we need to un-comment back the official repository locations and comment our newly added ISO repository.

Un-mount the ISO

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

Comment: what do you mean by comment.........?
Comment out all other repository locations from the file except the about one. Update the system

Comment: Add # in front of all the other lines in the file except that the one you just added.

Comment: Source https://bhutanict.blogspot.com/2014/06/update-kali-linux-from-iso-image-with.html ?

Answer (score 1):

The "uncomplicated way" (aka "without editing config files way") would be:

Copy all `*.deb` files from the iso/disc to `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

You can do this by mounting the iso-image to `/mnt` and then run

```
find /mnt -r -name *.deb -type f -exec cp {} /var/cache/apt/archives/ \;
```

Run

```
aptitude update; aptitude autoclean;
```

to delete all old debs from the cache directory and then upgrade like you would always do. apt/aptitude will now only download files you don't have in your cache.